Accumulated charge in conductors
Conductors placed in electric fields undergo a redistribution of charges. There is a separation of charges which occurs only on the surface. But what prevents the charge from leaving the surface of the conductor and move in the surrounding of the conductor?

By "leaving the surface of the conductor" do you mean "moving into the interior of the conductor" or "moving out of the conductor into the surrounding space"?

(1) If your question is why the charge doesn't leave the metal, the answer is that there is an energy barrier (usually on the order of an electron volt) called work function which prevents the electrons to leave the metal surface. At very high applied electric fields the electrons can leave the metal by tunneling through this surface barrier which is called Fowler-Nordheim tunneling. This leads to the "field emission" of electrons.
(2) The mobile charges in metals always reside on the surface and not in the interior because of the mutual repulsion of mobile charges (electrons) until the electric field and thus currents in the interior of the metal becomes zero.
